# How to convert gchar to char?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, gtk

i am trying to convert gchar to char by this code

```
const gchar * AddressText ;
char * AddressValue = (char *) AddressText ;
inet_pton(AF_INET,AddressValue, &Addr.sin_addr);
```

to use it in socket but it seems to not work

Comment: a `gchar` is either a `signed char` or an `unsigned char` in practice. So you can cast it as you do. Perhaps `AddressText` does not contain an IP *address* like `127.0.0.1` (it cannot be a host name like `localhost`...). Add for debugging a printing of `AddressText` which in your code is not initialized.

Comment: i am already passed the value 127.0.0.1 as address and print it with g_print()

Comment: "seems to not work". Zero information here. What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Comment: the actual result is : i get connection refused when trying to connect to the server and the expected result is get connection because i am passing the address of the server which is 127.0.0.1 by gtk_entry

Answer (score 3):

Your question "How to convert `gchar` to `char`" has a simple answer, but I don't think it's the question you meant to ask...

`gchar`, used in gtk, is a glib type [just a typedef to a `char`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.37/glib-Basic-Types.html#gchar), so you're done already.

What you're probably trying to ask is "why doesn't my code work", and that requires more code to answer. The [`inet_pton()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html) function needs the `src` parameter (your `AddressValue`) to be populated and since you're passing `AF_INET` it needs to be populated with an IPv4 address.

The code you're showing passes an uninitialized char pointer to this function...
So either that is your problem, or you are not showing your actual code, which means no one can help you.

**Note:** If you're getting "Connection refused" on 127.0.0.1 there's a good chance your server on your machine isn't running... or (if you wrote it yourself) the problem is with the connection code.

Comment: thanks for your reply 
now the code working when i removes the casting to AddressText 

char * AddressValue =  AddressText ;